# Can i load images from other websites and display into my website?

Tags: seo, html

Is loading the images from other sites into mysite is good?

Will it affect my website in anyways like speed, seo, copyright?

please don't mark this ques as off topic or duplicate. I need a clear understanding on this.

Comment: See also [Avoid Copyright Infringment through hotlinking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60510/avoid-copyright-infringment-through-hotlinking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking to images on other websites is called *hotlinking*.

> Can i load images from other websites and display into my website?

Yes. But the other website could (try to) block you.

> Is loading the images from other sites into mysite is good?

Not really. Good for who? The site you are hotlinking images from would *probably* not like it. (Whether it actually *helps* the external site SEO-wise is debatable - I thought there was a another recent Webmasters question relating to this specific point, but I can't seem to find it?)

> Will it affect my website in anyways like speed, seo, copyright?

The good things from your point of view:

- It doesn't cost you any bandwidth.
- If the external site is fast (or located near to your users) then it might even improve your perceived site speed.

The bad...

- The image it out of your control. The external site could block you or change the image at anytime without your knowledge.
- The image might indeed be copyright (as with any image). So, you could potentially face legal issues.
- If the external site is slow then your site is slow.
- It won't do anything for your SEO.

**See also:**

- [Is in-line linking (hot linking) photos and videos OK on my website, or is it unfair to the site which hosts them?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91779/is-in-line-linking-hot-linking-photos-and-videos-ok-on-my-website-or-is-it-un)

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm getting those image external links through the API .. for example I'm getting recent news info from an API so those images are already allowed by the sites right so i won't get any copyright issues or site blocking kind of things right? .. and will this hotlinking helps my site's seo in any way?

Comment: If the “API” you are getting this content from is trusted and this is the intended use of this content then there should not be any problems. (But this would seem to dramatically change the angle of your question?) This “hotlinking” won’t “help” your site’s SEO.